# Local Unit Test Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-instrumentation

Can someone show me a working code to do a unit test on this code?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
}
```

Please show me using local unit test(roboelectric.. etc, if possible) and instrumentation test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously the test will check if there is a button with a text *Login* created.

Comment: Did you try to read any documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robotium/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Expresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/):

```
if(onView(withText("Login")).exists()){ 
    doSomething(); 
} else { 
   doSomethingElse(); 
}
```

Here are the [details](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/) on how to  setup using Expresso.

Comment: how do I learn to integrate junit and mockito in above framework